# How to configure autotools/gcc to print warnings and errors with the absolute path?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, gcc-warning

I'm compiling an **autotools C based project** and I'm getting some warnings and errors. They are displayed like this:

```
foo.c:123: warning: some message
```

I would like them to be displayed like this:

```
/full/path/to/foo.c:123: warning: some message
```

I know this is not configurable through *gcc* except by passing to it the full file path itself, so I guess that this must be configurable through *autoconf/automake*.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do that and suspect that it cannot be done. **BUT** if your higher goal is to *find the files referenced by the warnings* it may be enough to use Emacs:

Open a file in the top source directory, like `C-x C-f configure.ac RET`, run the compilation: `M-x compile RET` (possibly edit the `make` command) `RET`. When you see a warning in the compilation buffer, use `C-x backtick` (C-x `) to display the source location.

Emacs manages this by parsing the "Entering directory /foo" and "Leaving directory /foo" messages from `make` so you may want to emulate that.

Comment: I use Emacs and it works like you said. I'll mark this as the answer, but if someone posts a more generic solution I'll accept that instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick that may work for you.

One can add the following line in `Makefile.am`

```
VPATH = $(abs_srcdir)
```

This will generate `Makefile` that will search source directory by referring the directory via absolute path. In turn, gcc will receive absolute paths for the source files.

I am NOT sure this trick will work for all vesions of make. In some versions of make the value of variable `VPATH` is read as flat text and make does not substitute the value of `abs_srcdir`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do this, but it might cause problems with other autotools `make` targets (e.g. `make dist`), so I'd advise against it.  There are absolute analogs to the `top_srcdir`, `top_builddir`, `srcdir` and `builddir` variables prefixed with `abs_` (e.g. `abs_top_srcdir`).  So you might try prefixing your source files with these before compiling them with gcc.

I'm not sure why you think that autotools should do this. How warnings/errors are printed out is a feature of the C compiler (gcc), not of autotools.

Answer (score 0):

For out of tree builds, there is a difference in the file names used to refer to source files between

```
mkdir _build
cd _build
../source-tree/configure --prefix=...
```

and

```
mkdir _build
cd _build
$PWD/../source-tree/configure --prefix=...
```